# Rails - query to group sums

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to build a query that does the following:

- The goal: to show the total number of visits to **all** the company's products on each day this month.
- First: We find all users that belong to *any* @company.product (each user has a product_id).
- Sum all visit counts among these users, grouping by day, for each of the last 30 days.
- To present these visit_count sums as a string of 30 comma-separated values (23,26,21,63,21,42 etc.) in the view.

So far (no sums yet):

```
#controller
@visits = User.group("date(created_at)").having("product_id IN (?) AND created_at > ?", @company.products.select("id"), 1.month.ago).order("created_at").select("visit_count")  
  # this simpler version causes error: undefined method 'empty?' for 2010-10-03 17:55:57 UTC:Time
  @visits = User.group("created_at").having("date(created_at) > (?)", 1.month.ago)

#view:
<%= @visits.map(&:visit_count).join(",")
```

The above query raises an error (3 arguments for 2), but I've tried many combinations similar to this and I keep getting errors. I'm just not too experienced with ActiveRecord. How would one write this query? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me...

```
User.group("DATE(created_at)").having(['created_at > ?', 1.month.ago]).count
```

yields...

```
=> {"2011-01-19"=>2, "2011-01-27"=>1}
```